# Manipulate particles spawned by SKEmitterNode

Tags: sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I want to emit particles using `SKEmitterNode` within a macOS app to create an effect similar to rain. No problem so far.

What I’m not able to figure out is: **Is it possible to let these emitted particles respond i.e. to mouseEvents, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not.

From the `SKEmitter` class reference docs at  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skemitternode

> Particles are not represented by objects in SpriteKit. This means you
>   cannot perform node-related tasks on particles, nor can you associate
>   physics bodies with particles to make them interact with other
>   content.

and

> Particles are purely visual objects, and their behavior is entirely
>   defined by the emitter node that created them.